# Error connecting with an c# client to an c server

Tags: c#, c, tcp, client, server

I'm trying to connect my c# client to my c server.
The client is on Windows and the server on Linux.

The server runs without errors but the client can't connect, the connection times out.

c server:

```
int main()
{
int socketid;
int clientid = 0;
char bufer[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
int addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

printf("Start\n");

if((socketid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    printf("Error ceating socket!\n%s", strerror(errno));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
printf("S0cket created\n");
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = 802;

if(bind(socketid, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
printf("Bindend\n");
listen(socketid, 0);
printf("Listening\n");

printf("Entering loop\n");
while(1)
{
    sleep((50)*1000);
    clientid = accept(socketid, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &addrlen);
    if(clientid > 0){printf("accepted");}else{printf("error");}
}
}
```

C# client:

```
void btnClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("192.168.1.102", 802);
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or just a time out?

Comment: I get a timeout exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux you definitely need this :

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(802);
```

because you need to go form host to network order.
So your server is actually listening to a different port than what you expected. ie 802 byte reversed.

Comment: ping the server ip address you want to access. Check that  there is no firewall, run the server and the client locally first before moving to a remote machine.

Comment: ping works, there isn't a firewall, and the compiler gives errors if i run it on windows so i can't run it locally.

The client still gives a SocketExeption.

Comment: create a c# server as well and test locally first. If everything is stable then go remote. You can also use ethereal to check the packets that are being sent and received. Switch of windows firewall on both sending and receiving machine.

Comment: The c# server and c# client can connect, no errors and the firewall is off, but still SocketException.

Comment: at what line do you get the exception ? And is this with still with the linux server or are you talking about the c# server now ?

Comment: The exception is at the "client.Connect()" line, and that's only with the linux server

Comment: run wireshark on both machines and see what is coming on the wire. Filter on tcp. https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: Done that on both machines and the client machine sends the tcp request and the server machine receives it, but the server itself does nothing.

Comment: remove the sleep from the server code, accept is a blocking call anyway, there is no need for a sleep. Sorry I did not notice this earlier.

Comment: Still no reaction of the server

Comment: execute netstat on your linux machine and check the ports that are being listened on : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/netstat-command-examples/

Comment: 803 or 802. btw your linux code was in fact wrong and my answer is in fact correct. At least upvote my answer as usefull .

Comment: I mean 802. And i've set it as usefull

Comment: hm, now we are at the point that i would have to come and take a look at your pc and do some debugging myself. you are sure that you've tried wireshark on the linux machine and seen those tcp packets ?

Comment: Yup, every time the client tries to connect, tshark displays it

Comment: then you should see the "accepted" trace coming out of the linux server. Of course that is all that is doing. Because you are not receiving anything nor sending anything in that server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to do port forwarding on linux. The firewall setting of linux don't allow any data to be receive on server.

1. go to system tab-> administration.
2. select firewall
3. select other ports
4. add the port you want the server to use

Now run your server